# Why php can not read encode values send from flutter?

Tags: php, flutter, dart

I was trying to get values by different post types in php

```
$data['data'] = 'request';
$data['_REQUEST'] = $_REQUEST;
$data['_POST'] = $_POST;
$data['_SERVER'] = $_SERVER;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Which was perfectly, even now working in the postman.

In the flutter I am trying following script, in which I encoded body values for sending with headers.

```
Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "x-auth": auth_token
    };
    
    final json = jsonEncode({
      "add_view_posty": 'yes',
      "post_id":'1'
    });
    http.Response response = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: json);
```

But php `_REQUEST` and `_POST` post type does not reading values send by above script. For above scripr I am not able to access `response.body` but `response.status` shows `200` response.

Following http request was working perfectly but it had no headers.

```
final json = {
      "add_view_posty": 'yes',
      "post_id":'1'
    };
    var data = await http.post(url, body: json);
```

Can someone kindly help I would like to appreciate. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
final body = {
  'name': 'Bob',
  'age': '87',
};
final jsonString = json.encode(body);
final uri = Uri.http('www.example.com', '/path');
final headers = {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'};
final response = await http.post(uri, headers: headers, body: jsonString);
```

In case it doesn't work for you, could you share with us how you make the request in postman

Comment: And also share the actual data sent over the wire.  And have you tested your PHP app with Postman?